# Deezer API, 30 Seconds preview doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, api, deezer

I’m using the deezer JavaScript SDK for my non commercial project.
It works fine when I’m logged but without login the 30 seconds preview doesn’t work
Chrome reports as an error a GET request to "www.deezer.com/plugins/undefined"
What does it mean? How can i fix this problem?

Here it is the code for the player:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        DZ.init({
            appId: '277462',
            channelUrl: 'http://www.symphonyproject.altervista.org/channel.php',
            player: {
                container: 'player',
                cover: true,
                playlist: true,
                width: 650,
                height: 300,
                onload: onPlayerLoaded
            }
        });





    });
        function onPlayerLoaded() {
            $("#controlers input").attr('disabled', false);
            DZ.Event.subscribe('current_track', function(arg){
                event_listener_append('current_track', arg.index, arg.track.title, arg.track.album.title);
            });
            DZ.Event.subscribe('player_position', function(arg){
                event_listener_append('position', arg[0], arg[1]);
                $("#slider_seek").find('.bar').css('width', (100*arg[0]/arg[1]) + '%');
            });




        function event_listener_append() {
            var pre = document.getElementById('event_listener');
            var line = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                line.push(arguments[i]);
            }
            pre.innerHTML += line.join(' ') + "\n";
        }
```

Comment: you probably have an undefined variable being used on line 37

Comment: On line 37 of what? My code or deezer api code? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: exactly my point - you've shown no code at all - most likely you've written code wrong, but, who really knows except you

Comment: i've updated the response with the code, can you check that?

Comment: so where's the request to `www.deezer.com`

Comment: it's in the API, it's not in my code

Comment: I set the settings according to the deezer tutorial, but the preview doesn't work anyway